# keras model.summary() don't show all model layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I build a keras functionnal model and when I plot the summary, the first conv1d layer don't appear...

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Dropout, TimeDistributed, Conv1D, 
     MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Model, regularizers, initializers

tensor_input = Input(shape=(Xn.shape[1], Xn.shape[2]), name='main_inputs')

xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters= 10, kernel_size= 3,
                            activation=params['activationCNN1']))
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2))

xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size= 2,
                        activation=params['activationCNN1']), name='Cnn1d-2')
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2), name='MaxPool')
xy = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name='Flatten')

xy = LSTM(params['unitsLstm1'],activation=params['activationLSTM1'],
          return_sequences=False, stateful=params['stateful'], 
          name='Hlayer1')(tensor_input)
xy = Dropout(rate = params['dropout1'])(xy)

xy = Dense(params['unitsDense1'], activation=params['activationDense1'],
           kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(), name='Dense1')(xy)
xy = Dropout(rate = params['dropout2'])(xy)

out = Dense(autres_param['timestepsOut'], activation=params['activationDenseOutput'],
            kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(), name='DenseOutput')(xy) 
model = Model(inputs=tensor_input, outputs=out)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=params['loss'])
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

What I get is: only  the input, lstm, dropout and dense layers...

[image: summary output]

The trainning seem to work but all layer are active? How can I get the full summary??

Comment: Ooh, I see the bug :) hint: `TimeDistributed` is also a layer and needs to be connected to the input

Comment: ohhhh ... yeahhh total newbi error, sorry for this dumb question it is ambarrassing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call each layer on the previous ouput tensor:

```
tensor_input = Input(shape=(Xn.shape[1], Xn.shape[2]), name='main_inputs')

xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters= 10, kernel_size= 3,
                            activation=params['activationCNN1']))(tensor_input)
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2))(xy)

xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size= 2,
                        activation=params['activationCNN1']), name='Cnn1d-2')(xy)
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2), name='MaxPool')(xy)
xy = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name='Flatten')(xy)

xy = LSTM(params['unitsLstm1'],activation=params['activationLSTM1'],
          return_sequences=False, stateful=params['stateful'], 
          name='Hlayer1')(xy)
```

In general, the summary is good at showing all part of the model. If something is not shown in the summary, it's safe to assume that that means that *it's not in the model*.

Answer (score 0):

In

```py
xy = LSTM(params['unitsLstm1'],activation=params['activationLSTM1'],
          return_sequences=False, stateful=params['stateful'], 
          name='Hlayer1')(tensor_input)
```

you call the `LSTM` on `tensor_input`, so basically all this:

```py
xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters= 10, kernel_size= 3,
                            activation=params['activationCNN1']))
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2))

xy = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size= 2,
                        activation=params['activationCNN1']), name='Cnn1d-2')
xy = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2), name='MaxPool')
xy = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name='Flatten')
```

is ignored.

Comment: I now understand why the trainning run so fast!!